# Array string grouping into specific sets

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting

I have an array of multiple sets of alpha numeric characters which i want to separate as groups.
For Example:
Array 1[] = {AAAAAAABBBBBBB1111111}
Needs to be grouped as AB1, AB1, AB1......

How can I do this?

Sometimes the number of characters might not be equal, example there might be 6 A's, 5 B's and 6 1's.

Comment: Hi, have corrected the question. The array gets the data from openCV haar cascade processing. I want to group it so that it can be compared with a template.

Comment: So what will be the output when character not be equal like you said above?

Comment: Last group will be just 'AB'

Comment: How is 'ABB111' split into groups?

Comment: It would be AB1, B1, 1

Comment: So chars already used in one group should not be used in the next group? What if it was `AB112`? I'm guessing `AB12`, `1`? The rules for the grouping are not very clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp25
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str1 = "AAAAAAABBBBBBB1111111";
            var result1 = Do(str1);


            var str2 = "AAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB111111111111111111111";
            var result2 = Do(str2);


            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result1));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result2));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string[] Do(string str)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<char, List<char>>();

            foreach (var c in str)
            {
                if (!dic.ContainsKey(c))
                {
                    dic.Add(c, new List<char>());
                }

                dic[c].Add(c);
            }

            var result = new List<string>();

            while (dic.Any(c => c.Value.Any()))
            {
                var tmpResult = new List<char>();

                foreach (var key in dic.Keys)
                {
                    if (dic[key].Any())
                    {
                        tmpResult.Add(key);
                        dic[key].Remove(key);
                    }
                }

                result.Add(new string(tmpResult.ToArray()));
            }

            return result.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

output1:

```
AB1 AB1 AB1 AB1 AB1 AB1 AB1
```

output2:

```
AB1 AB1 AB1 AB1 AB1 AB1 AB1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 1 1 1 1 1
```